# AlertDialog.Builder with custom layout fails to open?

Tags: java, android, layout, dynamic, spinner

In My Application I'm trying to `open a DialogBox` with `two Spinner` which I've define in `custom layout`. For Spinner's items I'm defining a `arraylist` with dropdown items, that when selected perform particular function. During Compilation it shows no error but when trying to `open dialog box` the application crashes.

Code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder rdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            rdialog.setTitle("Flavours");
            rdialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_get);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            alertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rptsetting,null);

            Spinner fSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fSpinner);
            ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList1.add("Chocolate");
            arrayList1.add("vanila");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrayList1);
            fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);
            fSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            Spinner phSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.phSpinner);
            ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList2.add("9991734971");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrayList2);
            phSpinner.setAdapter(adp1);
            phSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            EditText phNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phNumber);
            rdialog.setView(alertView);
            rdialog.setNeutralButton("SUBMIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();   
                    }
                });

            AlertDialog rdialog1 = rdialog.create();
            rdialog1.show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace this

```
 Spinner fSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fSpinner);
 Spinner phSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.phSpinner);
```

With

```
 Spinner fSpinner = (Spinner)alertView.findViewById(R.id.fSpinner);
 Spinner phSpinner = (Spinner)alertView.findViewById(R.id.phSpinner);
```

And also change if  `EditText` comes from your `Custom Dialog layout` then

```
EditText phNumber = (EditText)alertView.findViewById(R.id.phNumber);
```

Comment: @M D is there any way can i use `switch case` for the `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: @M D what function can be used to add functionality to `ArrayList<String>` item. Like if `click` vanila  a new `dialog box` may open

Comment: @Androidbeginner it's very simple. create another `Alert Dialog` into your `phSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {...}`